# PHP form redirects on script on submission in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have been trying to create a simple contact form using HTML and PHP. But I have found that:

1. Upon form submission, the form redirects to my script on chrome.
2. The form fails to send an email (I have replaced my email address for this example).

Can anyone see what the problem may be? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<form action="contact_script.php" method="post">
  Name<br>
  <input type="text" name="cf_name"><br>
  Telephone<br>
  <input type="text" name="cf_telephone"><br>
  E-mail<br>
  <input type="text" name="cf_email"><br>
  Enquiry<br>
  <textarea name="cf_message"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
  <input type="reset" value="Clear">
  </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
 $field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
 $field_telephone = $_POST['cf_telephone'];
 $field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
 $field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];


 $mail_to = 'myemail@mail.com';
 $subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

 $body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
 $body_message = 'Contact Number: '.$field_telephone."\n";
 $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
 $body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

 $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";  

 $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message);

 if ($mail_status) { ?>
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
      alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
      window.location = 'home.php';
    </script>
 <?php
 }
 else { ?>
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to info@mail.com');
         window.location = 'home.php';
     </script>
 <?php 
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Remove your window.location from both scripts and check the Page source in your browser after you submit your form

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Unfortunately, it just does the same thing

Comment: `Upon form submission, the form redirects to my script on chrome.` what do you mean by this?

Comment: Which script is which? Could you put the names to the scripts

Comment: @Akshay, I mean that it when you click submit on the form, the page should redirect to my homepage but it instead redirects to the source code of my PHP script.

Comment: @chloe_12
`but it instead redirects to the source code of my PHP script.` Is php even running on your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is working fine. You have to check some points

1. Upload your scripts in your server. Do not run in localhost.
2. Check the action and script name is same.
3. Check mail to address is correct.
4. Check you are running your script in a php installed server.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It is still not working but I will keep trying.

Comment: Create email id using your cPanel. Sometime server doesn't send email for this reason.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I do not actually have cPnanel or a hosting panel of any sort as this is just a basic HMTL website which I have been creating using Notepad ++.

Comment: If you do not have server your php script will not be processed.